# How to get div to take up the whole of the body?

Tags: html, css

I have a notifications panel which I would like to take up the whole of the body without having to specify hard coded values such as `height: 100px;`. I need it to take up all of the space until it reaches the footer. ViewHeight does not work as it pushes the footer off the page which is not my intended actions. So far I have this:

https://jsfiddle.net/bfbfvop4/2/

Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) is something for you: `height: calc(100% - 100px);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you exactly want but mybe this helps.

There's a trick in css for this:

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0
}

div{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      
      
      
    </div>
    
    
    
  </body>
  
  
  
</html>
```

You just have to set **html** and **body** to height and width 100%. **margin:0** is there just for the body (usually it has a margin of 2-4 px). Then you can make any 'relative' element full-body size.

**EDIT 1**: As **@str** ,after you write this code you can use 'calc(100% - ' if you want some space left.

**EDIT 2** : Is this what you want? [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergiureznicencu/pwo3zLnw/)

The style is mostly in html (with style='' attrb.). I had to use **calc** so that you can see the footer too. 
'Holder' must have the height 100%.

Delete `min-height` from '**class="container-fluid body-content body"**' and replace it with '**height: calc(100% - 77px);**' (100%-full screen ;77px is 75px -nav height and 2 px for border). Make the footer realtive and delete 'left:0' and 'bottom:0'. Then set row's properties to

```
position: relative;
height: calc(100% - 77px);
```

(100% from its parent height -77px from height+border of the footer)

Comment: I already have that in css, I have tried changing all parent divs to 100% but it doesn't do anything

Comment: Try putting position:relative

Comment: Where did you wrote this code (the position:relative)? In which class?

Comment: Html,body and all other containers down to the notifications panel

Answer (score 1):

Worked out the answer thanks to @str and @sergiu reznicencu.

So what I did was calculate the height I wanted by doing this calculation:

```
height: calc(100vh - height of my navbar - height of my footer);
```

I then set the height for the body and panel to be this variable.

I used sass but you don't need sass to do this, just follow the above way.

OR `height: 85vh` worked fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.notifications {
  padding-right: 0px; 
  height:300px;
  }
  .notifications .notifications-panel {
    height:100%;
    background-color: #F5F5F5; }
```

Comment: I specified in my question that I wouldn't like to use hard coded values, thanks for the reply though

Comment: @AndrewKilburn What about jquery could use that.

Comment: I thought about that but it wouldn't work as I don't have a div which takes up the whole space between the nav and footer. Besides, it would also be inefficient

Comment: @AndrewKilburn Then you have to set footer position to relative.